# Is setting php.ini's session.auto_start to 1 considered bad practice?

Tags: session, php

I was playing around with php.ini's session.start_auto and tried setting it to 1. The site I am building requires session management on every page anyways and the server only contains the one site. Is this considered bad practice (like having globals turned on - which I dont BTW!) - php.net doesn't say a lot about it.

Comment: or simply use `if (ini_get('session.auto_start') == 0) session_start();` to prevent Notices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- IMO relying on `php.ini` settings can be tricky if people deploying your app don't have control on the `php.ini` (e.g. shared hosting). And even if the `php.ini` can be changed, understanding a problem due to a `php.ini` configuration problem may be difficult to understand (you may have to write a script allowing to check if config is Ok, etc.).
- As an alternative, you can create a unique "controller" script (e.g. `/index.php`), which will call and output different pages depending on parameters sent to it (e.g. `yoursite.com/index.php?page=12` or even better `yoursite.com/page/12` with routing & URL rewriting). And in that **index.php** file, put your `session_start()` once for all pages.

Comment: I'd have voted this up for the first point, but voted it down for suggesting a front controller as a solution %) (you could get the same benefit by using an auto-prepend without having to rewrite the entire site - and if you are rewritnig the entire site, wouldn't it be simpler to just add session_start()...not to mention all the other issues with FC)

Comment: @symcbean `auto_prepend_file` relies on `php.ini` too. IMO using a FC is preferable to repeating `session_start();` on every page: pros  look far stronger than cons, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121849/pros-and-cons-of-using-one-file-for-entire-webpage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538242/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-specifying-a-controller-class-via-url-vs-having-a http://css.dzone.com/books/practical-php-patterns/practical-php-patterns-front

Answer (score 2):

Nah, why should it be? In principle, its the same as having `session_start();` as the second line in every page.

Comment: You are assuming that putting session_start() on every page is not a bad thing. If someone enters your site, reads some pages and then leaves, why would a session need to be created? It's pretty rare that ALL your pages needs a session.

Comment: @DanieleTesta, yes, but the question explicitly said that his every page indeed uses the session. (Otherwise yes, there are good reasons to avoid the default PHP session setup, e.g. if you need to customize properties of the session cookie.)

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I would consider it BAD to turn auto_session on. Like other people said, it is the same thing as putting a session_start() on ALL your pages.

Imagine all people that enters the main page of your website. A session will be created even before they tried to login or anything else. All spam-bots, all search engine bots etc will all create a session when entering your page. This is usually a bad thing as it will create TONS of files on your server (if session is file-based) or fill your ram cache (if session is memcache based).

It's much better to simply run session_start() only when you actually NEED a session. You can just create a "session class" or simple functions like session_get() and session_put() which will run session_start() for you. Then use those instead of $_SESSION directly.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the answer is "yes, it is bad practice."

[disclaimer: I started building web pages in 1997 -- when you coded everything by hand, so I have developed my own way of doing things.]

In my world, I have a MySessionHandler which extends SessionHandler.  It pulls in an INI file that contains all of the ini_set commands needed.  I note that I am not the only one who does this.  If you auto-start the session (which happens before the code gets executed), then a number of the frameworks also have issues.

The first line of executable code in my PHP scripts is a require of MySessionHandler.php, which starts off by checking the values of auto-start and use_strict_mode, optionally dying with an error if they are not set properly.

Answer (score 0):

As you can start session in read-only mode to gain better performance and avoid session file locking, I prefer manually start sessions.