# Is there a downside to session.auto_start in PHP?

Tags: session, php

I usually end up adding `session_start()` to the top of every page on my PHP sites (or in a header file which is in turn included on every page). I recently discovered that you can have sessions start automatically by using the following setting in `php.ini`:

`session.auto_start = 1`

What are the potential downsides (if any) of using this setting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is setting php.ini's session.auto\_start to 1 considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257083/is-setting-php-inis-session-auto-start-to-1-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If you turn on **[session.auto_start](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start)** then the only way to put objects
>   into your sessions is to load its class definition using
>   auto_prepend_file in which you load the class definition else you will
>   have to **[serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)** your object and **[unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)** it afterwards. [See](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php).

Comment: So what you're saying is that if I use session.auto_start, then I won't be able to freely use $_SESSION variables?

Comment: 1)if you use `session.auto_start` you'll not be able to use named sessions but since you have access to `php.ini` I dont think that will be much of a problem. 2)URL may look messy, if the client does not support cookies.

Comment: Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257083/is-setting-php-inis-session-auto-start-to-1-considered-bad-practice) question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps.   It will create a session if there is no session created on page load.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)): session_start();endif;
```

If you want to start a specific session, then use something like this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['your_session'])){             
            $data = array('default data');
            $_SESSION['your_session']=$data;
        }
```